# How to prepopulate form in struts2 from database values

Tags: java, html, struts2

I want to show an edit form where user can change its old data.
So i want to prepoulate form with values picked up from databaase?

Please tell me how to do this in struts2?

Comment: Try to populate the data in the bean, then it is accessible to the corresponding forwarding jsp via struts tags.

Comment: Can you provide me example/link for that

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_database_access.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This interceptor calls prepare() on actions which implement
>   Preparable. This interceptor is very useful for any situation where
>   you need to ensure some logic runs before the actual execute method
>   runs.

[PreparableInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/docs/prepare-interceptor.html)

Example :
[Struts2 UI Tags similar to pre-population logic.](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ui-tags-example-1.html)

```
package com.examples;
public class RegistrationAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // get the data that you want to pre-populate
    }

    public String execute() {
        // you action logic
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}



<!-- Calls the params interceptor twice, allowing you to pre-load data for the second time parameters are set -->
<!-- don't forgot to add prepare interceptor to interceptor stack -->
 <action name="someAction" class="com.examples.RegistrationAction">
     <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
     <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
     <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
     <result name="success">good_result.ftl</result>
 </action>
```